# Get latest record from a grouping and filter on status

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table list where when grouping by an identifier (`gtin`) I want to grab the latest record in that list based on the `createdDateTime` and from that list I only want to return the ones that are `unassigned`.

If I have a list like so

```
GTIN | CreatedDate | status
123    12/19/2018    assigned
123    12/20/2018    unassigned
123    12/21/2018    closed
```

Then this code

```
var ordered = query.GroupBy(o => o.gtin)
             .Select(o => o.OrderByDescending(p => p.createdDateTime).FirstOrDefault())
             .Where(o => o != null && o.status == "Unassigned");
```

when run I expect no records for 123 to come back because the latest  created date for 123 is the 12/21 and the status is `closed` and not `unassigned`.
what actually happens is that I get a 123 record and it appears unassigned.
so the issue is that my `select` is not bringing back a list of the latest record as I thought.

Comment: It isn't possible for `o` to be `null`. You can just use `First` instead of `FirstOrDefault`. Show the code for your entities - what is the actual type of `CreatedDate`?

Comment: @NetMage CreatedDate is  a `DateTime` when I tried to put in just First I get an error that I have to use FirstOrDefault because it is not the end of a query

Comment: Is this linq to sql?  If so I’d use the long for “from” syntax and left joint it to itself.   I’m away from my computer now but if you’d want to see what it’d look like I will check back and write it up.   But maybe it’s not what you are looking for.

Comment: Unassigned is really stored in a enum. but I wrote it out here to make it easier. the data types don't matter here. because I am getting unassigned records back its just that one that should not come back does. I tried to boil this down to as low as possible where is someone can recreate it. the issue is with the select not getting the latest record. that is my question.

Comment: NetMage: although you are right about the First instead of FirstOrDefault, IQueryable doesn't allow First as property value in a Select, so you'll have to use FirstOrDefault

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> I expect no records for 123 to come back because the latest created date for 123 is the 12/21 and the status is closed and not unassigned

Are you sure? I tried the following code:

```
enum Status { unassigned, assigned, closed };
class MyType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IEnumerable<MyType> items = new List<MyType>
    {
        new MyType {Id = 123, CreationDate = new DateTime(2018, 12, 19), Status = Status.assigned},
        new MyType {Id = 123, CreationDate = new DateTime(2018, 12, 20), Status = Status.unassigned},
        new MyType {Id = 123, CreationDate = new DateTime(2018, 12, 21), Status = Status.closed},
    };

    var a = items.GroupBy(o => o.Id);
    var b = a.Select(o => o.OrderByDescending(p => p.CreationDate).FirstOrDefault());
    var c = b.Where(o => o != null && o.Status == Status.unassigned);
}
```

My debugger tells me:

```
- `a` is a sequence with one element: an `IGrouping<MyType>` with `Key` equal to 123, and a sequence of all three elements
- 'b' is also a sequence of one element, but now a sequence of `MyType`. This one element is the element with Date 21 dec 2018 and status Closed
- `c` is an empty sequence
```

Isn't this what you wanted and expected?

Comment: OK, so this just confuses me more, because my linq query is correct. but running it always brings back that one record. also I ran a select in SQL Management against that same database for that specific record and it does come with the unassigned one that has the create date earlier than other records. but thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the latest `Unassigned` member based on `CreatedDate`, you can to check for the condition in `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var firstOrder = list
                 .GroupBy(obj => obj.gtin)
                 .FirstOrDefault(obj => obj.Key == 123)
                 ?.OrderByDescending(obj => obj.createdDateTime)
                 .FirstOrDefault(o => o.status == "Unassigned");
```

But if you want the return the latest if it is `Unassigned` and return null if it is not, you can't do it with LINQ. you have to add an `if` condition:

```
var firstOrder = list
                 .GroupBy(obj => obj.gtin)
                 .FirstOrDefault(obj => obj.Key == 123)
                 ?.OrderByDescending(obj => obj.createdDateTime)
                 .FirstOrDefault();

if (firstOrder?.status == "Unassigned")
{
    //proceed with firstOrder
}
```